# Python 3.3 itertools map of length 5 filtered by regular expression levels

Tags: javascript, python, regex

**Disclaimer:** Hello, This is my first post on stackoverflow, though I have lurked this invaluable site for many months.  Please let me know if I have violated any procedures/committed noobish acts in this post.

**Summary:** What I am attempting to do is simulate all possible strings for the Regular expression set [A-Za-z0-9] of length 5, using the map function in python.  In addition each level has an additional Regular Expression that filters out possible answers, thus the final level should only produce 1 string. I should note what I am trying to find is the 1 answer to these regular expressions.  Note this is a puzzle that originally was in javascript, so if something looks out of place I have most likely done a poor translation.

**Problem:** I added added in print statements on level2 and it returns empty brackets.  This shouldn't be possible with what I have written.  Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?  Additionally the itertools map is a computationally intense process to finding this string/mapping these regular expressions, I am open to other possible approaches.  Thank you for your time.

** **Edited** ** formatting.

```
import re
import itertools
import string
for s in map(''.join, itertools.product((string.ascii_letters + string.digits), repeat=5)):
    rexp = re.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}")
    matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
#LEVEL 1
    if len(matches) !=0:
            rexp = re.compile("^[^e-z0-9A-Z]+[^A-Z]{4}{?[a-z]*_?")
            matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
#LEVEL 2
            if len(matches) !=0:
                    rexp = re.compile("^[A9FbdHh5]+[T]*.{2}_?[a-z]+")
                    matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
                    print("Level 2 Match Found: ", matches)
#LEVEL 3
                    if len(matches) !=0:
                            rexp = re.compile("^YdSeu][r]+[^r]+=?_?[aeiou]+[^pstuvwxyz]+")
                            matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
#LEVEL 4
                            if len(matches) !=0:
                                    rexp = re.compile("^(c|a|b|d)+
    [^A-Za-df-qs-z]{2}{?[^vCXBhq]*[^pqrst]*[a]+[^passwd]*}")
                                    matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
#LEVEL 5
                                    if len(matches) !=0:
                                            rexp = re.compile("^.*[k0pst]$")
                                            matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
#LEVEL 6
                                            if len(matches) !=0:
                                                    rexp = re.compile("^[^0-9A-Z]{5}$")
                                                    matches = re.findall(rexp, s)
                                                    print("Password Found: ", matches)
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("\n")
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Can you please link the original puzzle? It's hard to understand your code out of context.

Comment: Please see pastebin link below for original puzzle script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do ... but let's go back to basics. You are defining a universe with 62 items:

```
universe = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
```

And then you are trying to take the cross-product of 5 of those universes, which means roughly a billion combinations:

```
62 ** 5 = 916,132,832
```

And not only that ... you want to instantiate those billion things as a list.

```
map(''.join, itertools.product(universe, repeat=5))
```

One of the purposes of `itertools.product` is to avoid computing all of the combinations in advance (in memory). So we can rewrite your top-level code like this:

```
n_repeat = 5
for xs in itertools.product(universe, repeat = n_repeat):
    s = ''.join(xs)
```

A few other points:

- If you're writing code that must iterate over a billion items, you don't want to repeat computations. So compile all of your regular expressions in advance, before starting the big loop.
- While you're at it, rewrite those regular expressions to be parametizable, so that you can get your code working with a smaller N (less that 5) for the repeat value. Otherwise, you won't be able to iterate quickly as you work out the kinks in your algorithm.
- Why are you using `findall()` when your regular expressions are always anchored to the start of the string? Use `search()` or even `match()` instead.
- Your first and last regular expressions serve no purpose at all. By definition they will always succeed.
- There's no point in having an algorithm that tests a general regular expression (eg, level 1 or level 6), and also tests a very specific regular expression (eg, level 4). Just test the specific requirements and be done with it.
- Your regular expressions seem incompatible. How can a string begin with this: `^(c|a|b|d)`. And also being with this: `^Y`.

Comment: I am still in the process of implementing what you suggested.  However, here is the original puzzle script.
http://pastebin.com/A0KcRpaY

Comment: @user3023783 That JS code has many of the same problems and mysteries. For example, it's makes no sense to impose this requirement on a piece of text `^[A9FbdHh5]+`; followed by this requirement `^[^YdSeu]`; followed by this requirement `^(c|a|b|d)+`. The three requirements can be simplified to one test: `^b+`. Which raises another, more fundamental question: why use regular expressions at all (at least for that part of the problem)? Just check whether `s[0] == 'b'` and then proceed with the remaining validation on `s[1:5]`.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  As you can obviously see my programming skills are next to none.  I just started learning python 2 months ago.  In addition to that, this is my first bout with regular expressions.    Though this problem my still be outside the range of my abilities at the moment, I will analyze what you posted and implement it as I begin to understand it.  Thank you for your help and guidance.